# Single word meaning "containers used to transfer"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-usage

I have a sentence of the form: "*Y can be viewed as containers used to transfer X*", where X in my case is genetic information. It feels like this sentence could be simplified to something like "*Y can be viewed as a xxxx of X*", but I cannot find the proper word. In my particular case, the context is: "*male gametes can be viewed simply as containers used to transfer genetic information*", and the issue came up when answering a question at Biology-SE.

So, what I'm looking for is a replacement for "*containers used to transfer*". I've been thinking about using *vessel*, but dictionaries usually focus on vessel as a container of liquids (e.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vessel), beside the obvious meaning of *vessel* as *ship*. To me, *vessel* also feels a bit awkward to use in this case.

- Can *vessel* be used in my sentence?
- Is there another more suitable word to use?

Comment: What's wrong with simply "container"?

Comment: @HotLicks I considered that, but, to me, that lacks the connotations of motion.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=container&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Gs8KVb_tBcr5ggSswYPgBA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1049&bih=560

Comment: *transfer-containers*

Comment: @HotLicks That is a very specific use of 'container' and not the general meaning of the word ("anything that can contain something"), and it is hardly suitable to imply transfer at the molecular level (or in many other cases).

Comment: Maybe a vessel?

Comment: @SUMGUY - Make that a "nuclear wessel".

Comment: Let me get this straight:  You want a general-purpose single word that implies containment at the molecular level??

Comment: (And, BTW, that page is what I got when I asked for plain old "container" in Google Images.  I did not request a "specific" form.)

Comment: @HotLicks Are you intentionally trying to misunderstand me? No, I'm saying that 'container' is a more general term than simply 'shipping container', and for many purposes it does not imply movement. That there are many pictures on the web of shipping containers that have the word 'container' is the file name is hardly an authoritative source for how 'container' is used more generally.

Comment: 'transfer mechanism'

Comment: Could you give the entire sentence? What is _X_ here? That can completely change the wording. Also, please clarify the context in which you want to use the term you are searching for.

Comment: When discussing anything having to do with anatomy, "vessel" should be avoided unless it's talking about a blood vessel or some similar structure.  Again, there is absolutely nothing wrong withe "containers used to transfer"  -- I don't see why you're so resistant to that.  Are you being charged by the letter or something?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm fine with "*containers used to transfer*", but it felt a bit cumbersome and wordy, and I sensed that there should be a suitable single word. The suggested "*carrier*" is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell without more context, but presumably you are referring to some sort of sequence element. If so, you could use *carrier*:

> Y  can be viewed as carriers of genetic information.

Alternatively, you could rephrase. Something like

> Y encode genetic information.

Or, simply, if these are genes:

> Y codes for X.

Answer (score 6):

Usage of the word 'Vehicle', or 'Carton' may serve the purpose.

Comment: +1 for vehicle.  especially if this is something *machine-like* happening at the molecular or cellular level, such as the activity of amino acids within cells.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the word you're looking for is *conveyor* or *transporter*.
[The Free Dictionary - Conveyor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conveyor)

Comment: Depends where you live - 'carrier' would be the word of choice in the UK, rather than conveyor (which, here, suggests a moving belt of some sort).

Comment: @bamboo A _conveyor of information_ hardly suggests a moving belt.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet as I said, 'carrier' would be the UK word of choice  - doesn't mean it would be in other places though.

Answer (score 1):

I would rearrange the sentence, placing X before Y.  This isn't a solution to your word request, but it flows better.

Ex. *X is/are transferred within Y.*

Comment: if it's not an answer, better to put this in comments.